# Android - Debugging on device

Tags: android

How do I install the app that I'm making on an actual device?

I'm on Mac Snow Leopard with a Nexus One phone and I've followed the steps here https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html

So I added:
1. android:debuggable="true"
2. Turn on "USB Debugging" on your device.

However, when I go to the terminal and do "adb devices" only the emulator shows up there.
I'm supposed to see my device name too right?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The device didn't show up because of the cable.
Although the old cable was charging the phone, but for some reason it wasn't mounting the device and being new to Android, I just wasn't sure what I'm supposed to see and expect.

In case anyone is interested, there should be a "USB connected" notification if the mounting works.
(this is from menu > notification)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm supposed to see my device name too right?

Yes, you should see your device name right there.

> What am I missing?

This is weird. Is the Android phone at least recognized by the OS, as being plugged into the USB port?

(Sorry this won't help much...)

Comment: Thank espinchi. Yes I think the OS does recognize it since the green/orange light shows up.

Answer (score 0):

There is a App on the marketplace I use called App Installer, I just upload the apk file to my sd card then run app installer on it.

Answer (score -1):

My solution is simple, I email the `apk` file and then install it.

Comment: @rohit most important, it is in no way simple